# Access config file in nunit

Tags: c#, asp.net, nunit

I am using nunit in my application. I want to access config file situated in my test project. I created a fake context via this:

```
  HttpContext.Current = new HttpContext(
               new HttpRequest(null, "http://tempuri.org", null),
               new HttpResponse(null));
```

I can't access the config file by any of these:

```
System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/MyConfig.config")
HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath.MapPath("~/MyConfig.config")
System.Web.HttpServerUtility.MapPath("~/MyConfig.config")
```

Answer (score 0):

you config files do not get deployed to your Unit Tests.  There is an attribute that you can add to your tests called [DeployableItem] and it will point to your config.

[What does `DeploymentItem` attribute mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3958392/what-does-deploymentitem-attribute-mean)

[Xml file not copying to test output directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4369861/xml-file-not-copying-to-test-output-directory)

[DeploymentItem not deploying files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16787003/deploymentitem-not-deploying-files)